# Biblatex and thumbs package

Tags: biblatex

In the following example, I use "biblatex" and "thumbs" packages. I need an overview page of thumbs - see page 5 of the document. I have 13 chapter in my book, but only 6 chapter in the overview (see picture).

If I remove "biblatex" and "csquote" package from preamble, then I have, as forecasted my 13 chapter in my overview page.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[hyperindex=false, linktoc=all]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue}
\usepackage[thumblink=none,linefill=dots,height={auto},minheight={33pt},%
            width={40pt},distance={2mm},topthumbmargin={40pt},bottomthumbmargin={40pt},%
            nophantomsection=false,ignorehoffset=true,ignorevoffset=true,final=true,%
            hidethumbs=false,verbose=true]{thumbs}           
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear, backref, useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section*{Example for thumbs}
\tableofcontents
\addthumbsoverviewtocontents{chapter}{Thumb marks overview}
\thumbsoverview{Table of Thumbs}

\chapter{Chaptitre 1}
\addthumb{First Chap}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 2}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 2}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 3}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 3}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 4}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 4}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 5}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 5}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 6}
\addthumb{2Chaptitre 6}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 7}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 7}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 8}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 8}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 9}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 9}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 10}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 10}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 11}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 11}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 12}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 12}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 13}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 13}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compile 3 times.
Linux Debian Mint Edition, TeXLive, TeXmaker 4.5

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice problem!

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, it indeed disappears if `biblatex` is uncommented.

Comment: biblatex inserts lines in the .tmb-file (as it patches `\addtocontents`) and as thumbs inserts "line 1 to 13" of file tmb the count goes out of sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments biblatex patches \addtocontents to insert code in the various toc-files and so confuse the thumbs counter. You can patch thumbs like this:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

%save the old definition:
\let\oldaddtocontents\addtocontents

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear, backref, useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[hyperindex=false, linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue}

\usepackage[thumblink=none,linefill=dots,height={auto},minheight={33pt},%
            width={40pt},distance={2mm},topthumbmargin={40pt},bottomthumbmargin={40pt},%
            nophantomsection=false,ignorehoffset=true,ignorevoffset=true,final=true,%
            hidethumbs=false,verbose=true]{thumbs}

\usepackage{xpatch}
%restore (twice!) the definition in \addthumb:
\xpatchcmd{\addthumb}{\addtocontents}{\oldaddtocontents}{}{}            
\xpatchcmd{\addthumb}{\addtocontents}{\oldaddtocontents}{}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section*{Example for thumbs}
\tableofcontents

\addthumbsoverviewtocontents{chapter}{Thumb marks overview}
\thumbsoverview{Table of Thumbs}

\chapter{Chaptitre 1}
\addthumb{First Chap}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 2}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 2}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 3}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 3}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 4}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 4}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 5}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 5}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 6}
\addthumb{2Chaptitre 6}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 7}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 7}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 8}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 8}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 9}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 9}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 10}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 10}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 11}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 11}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 12}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 12}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chaptitre 13}
\addthumb{Chaptitre 13}{\Huge{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}}{white}{gray}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```